# UITouch is not working with ios8

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I am working on one app. Which capture images continuously, there is one button to stop capturing. But the problem is that button targeted method is not being called. Even when I clicked on the screen anywhere it didn't detect touch or gesture. I have implemented gesture and touch delegate methods to check. Capturing image is not on main thread so main thread is free. So I am not able to find the reason why view not able to detect the touch. There are almost 6-7 button on that particular view, none of them trigger their method. While working with ios7 its running properly, It will detect touch and button targeted method trigger also.

I have thought that there should be any-view that will be overlap those button so i print the stake of subview , which is as below.Button which stop capturing is with text "START". I have just share stake after START button only as i think in stake the last item will be on top in view.

```
<UIButtonLabel: 0x15dfb0d0; frame = (5 14; 41 16); text = 'START';
 opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer:
 0x15dfb190>>

 <UIButton: 0x15e8c590; frame = (63 7; 36 32); opaque = NO; autoresize
 = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x15e8c690>>

 <UIButtonLabel: 0x15df0400; frame = (15 10; 6 12); text = '0'; opaque
 = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x15d98db0>>

 <UIImageView: 0x15e97c00; frame = (-295 -272; 1557 1568);
 clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H;
 autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15ea2920>>

 <_UILayoutGuide: 0x15e90ba0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer =
 <CALayer: 0x15ea2b10>>

 <_UILayoutGuide: 0x15e86120; frame = (0 1024; 0 0); hidden = YES;
 layer = <CALayer: 0x15e6fc40>>

 <MPVolumeView: 0x15db7840; frame = (18 340; 284 23); alpha = 0; opaque
 = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15dbd2e0>>

 <UILabel: 0x15daee40; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'No Volume
 Available'; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; userInteractionEnabled =
 NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x15dd5be0>>

 <MPButton: 0x15dd5e00; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (131.5 2.5; 21.5
 18); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+BM; layer = <CALayer:
 0x15dd6030>>

 <UIImageView: 0x15de0c30; frame = (-39.25 -41; 100 100); alpha = 0;
 opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1886548836; layer =
 <CALayer: 0x15ea5330>>

 <UIImageView: 0x15ea5790; frame = (0 0; 21.5 18); clipsToBounds = YES;
 opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer:
 0x15ea5810>>
```

I am using auto-layout. Please can you help me to handle this problem. I am new with auto-layout. so anything that i can change in storyboard get this problem solved please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your button or view is on UIImageView, you have to setUserInteraction true to UIImageView.

Comment: Turn off autolayout and see what happens, you can easily undo it if all goes wrong.

Comment: @MichaelMooney : I have tried that but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Did you goto the view controller and goto the 'File inspector' and turn auto layout off that way (click the box), and if you did, you should try what @trick14 said, setUserInteraction to true.

Comment: I have tried that too. But still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers. I got solution by moving irate code from +initialize method of AppDelegate to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. My iRate get initialized and configure but don't show popup. May be that's why i was not able to perform any touch on screen.